# JSF 1.2 custom component does not render/encode children

Tags: jsf, custom-component, jsf-1.2

I have two custom components:

```
CustomUIComponent extends UIComponentBase
CustomChildUIComponent extends UIComponentBase
```

In CustomUIComponent I implement encodeBegin, encodeChildren and encodeEnd - in encodeChildren I set some custom attribute to be forwarded to the child component.

In CustomChildUIComponent I implement only encodeBegin.

In addition to these classes I added the components in the faces-config.xml:

```
<component>
    <component-type>test.JsfMessage</component-type>
    <component-class>test.CustomUIComponent</component-class>
</component>
<component>
     <component-type>test.JsfChildMessage</component-type>
     <component-class>test.CustomChildUIComponent</component-class>
</component>
```

And I have the custom taglib.xml configured in the web.xml and contains:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>customMessage</tag-name>
    <component>
        <component-type>test.JsfMessage</component-type>
    </component>
</tag>

<tag>
    <tag-name>customChildMessage</tag-name>
    <component>
        <component-type>test.JsfChildMessage</component-type>
    </component>
</tag>
```

Finally in my Facelets page I am trying to execute:

```
<myns:customMessage message="Hello World!!!" var="mytestvar">
    <myns:customChildMessage partnermsg="#{mytestvar}" />
</myns:customMessage>
```

The result is that the parent is rendered but the child component does not.

Am I doing something wrong?

I tried checking the super.encodeChildren but it checks:

```
Renderer renderer = getRenderer(context);
if(renderer != null) ...
```

I am not using a renderer class, but as I understand it is not a must.

Answer (score 2):

The [`encodeChildren()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#encodeChildren%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method of your custom component will only be called if the [`getRendersChildren()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#getRendersChildren%28%29) method of the very same custom component returns `true`. This is specified in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#encodeChildren%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29):

> This method will only be called if the `rendersChildren` property is `true`.

So make sure that you've overridden that accordingly, it namely defaults to `false`:

```
@Override
public boolean getRendersChildren() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the reply and sorry for late response :) I do have this overridden method in the code,but it still doesn't work...